# How to work with dynamic keys safely in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, key, type-safety

I'm looking for a safe way to create keyed objects like this:

```js
interface Statuses {
  WAITING: 'WAITING';
  IN_PROGRESS: 'IN_PROGRESS';
  RESOLVED: 'RESOLVED';
}

type StatusKeys = keyof Statuses;

const STATUS: Statuses = {
  WAITING: 'WAITING',
  IN_PROGRESS: 'IN_PROGRESS',
  RESOLVED: 'RESOLVED',
};
```

But I think it is a little uncomfortable and redundant to set this way, and I need to declare the values ​​twice.

Is there any better and safer way to do this?

In my React function it looks like this:

```js
const [status, setStatus] = useState<StatusKeys>(STATUS.WAITING);

const handleStatusChange = (
  event: React.ChangeEvent<{ name?: string; value: unknown }>
) => {
  const newStatusValue = event.target.value as StatusKeys;
  setStatus(newStatusValue);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer an `enum` for this case.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

```
enum Status {
  WAITING = "WAITING",
  IN_PROGRESS = "IN_PROGRESS",
  RESOLVED = "RESOLVED"
}

// ...

// Note you don't need to explicitly declare type here with <Status>.
// TS will automatically infer type of "status" as any Status enum value.
const [status, setStatus] = useState(Status.WAITING);

const handleStatusChange = (
  event: React.ChangeEvent<{ name?: string; value: Status }>
) => {
  const newStatusValue = event.target.value;
  setStatus(newStatusValue);
};
```

Why an `enum`? Generally they infer better, [can also work the same as string values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums), avoid duplication, and better match conceptually what the data represents (a fixed set of related values known in advance at "compile-time").

> Enums allow us to define a set of named constants. Using enums can make it easier to document intent, or create a set of distinct cases.

If you want to get the string values of your `enum` as an array, you can treat it as an object with `Object.keys()`:

```
const statuses = Object.keys(Status);
// ["WAITING", "IN_PROGRESS", "RESOLVED"]
```

Comment: I guess it worth mentioning that if you don't need to obtain the keys in any way, it's preferable to use `const enum` as it produce no extra code.